# SnappyData(Table is not showing in cluster)

Tags: java, eclipse, snappy, snappydata

I've created one program for snappy data in Java. 
I'm not able to get the table name in cluster. Also I'm can't understand the log file.  Any hints?

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
       .builder()
       .appName("SparkApp")
       .master("local[*]")
       .getOrCreate();
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
    SnappySession snappy = new SnappySession(spark.sparkContext());
    snappy.dropTable("CUSTOMER",true);
    snappy.sql("CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER ( " +
            "C_CUSTKEY     INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "C_NAME        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL," +
            "C_ADDRESS     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL," +
            "C_NATIONKEY   INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "C_PHONE       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL," +
            "C_ACCTBAL     DECIMAL(15,2)   NOT NULL," +
            "C_MKTSEGMENT  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL," +
            "C_COMMENT     VARCHAR(117) NOT NULL)" +
            "USING COLUMN OPTIONS (PARTITION_BY 'C_CUSTKEY')");
}
```

Comment: Firstly i created the jar then in my master ,through this command i run "$SNAPPY_HOME bin/run-example jarName.jar"...

Comment: Can you please elaborate where you are checking. $SNAPPY_HOME bin/run-example  will run Spark in a local mode.

Comment: yes in a local machine i run that command , so many logs are came ,in this some processing in that sql create command but not geeting table in the cluster

Comment: Where are you checking for the table name? This is local[\*] mode so only that program can see the table (or in Spark GUI on port 4040). If you have a query like: snappy.sql("select count(*) from CUSTOMER").collect(), in that code snippet above does it work or not?

Comment: i am checking in my snappy cluster,   snappy.sql("select count(*) from CUSTOMER").collect() this line not working

Comment: This is local[\*] mode so where exactly is the cluster? My question was whether that line is working or not in the above program snippet i.e. if you add it immediately after the CREATE TABLE above then does it work or not. Also when you say "not working" then does it fail with some exception?

Comment: that line not worked, and it doesn't show any exception . And my cluster in local machine only

Comment: I think the reason you are not getting any output from this line is that you have not inserted any rows in the table  snappy.sql("select count(*) from CUSTOMER").collect(). And if you change that line to snappy.sql("select count(*) from CUSTOMER").show() it will show you actual count of the table, which is 0 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are not getting any output from this line is that you have not inserted any rows in the table snappy.sql("select count() from CUSTOMER").collect(). And if you change that line to snappy.sql("select count() from CUSTOMER").show() it will show you actual count of the table, which is 0 in your example.

Comment: but table name also not showing.. if table is created...so it will also show there.